What IP to assign my NIC in order to receive multicast traffic
I have a device (Blackmagic 2110 IP Converter 3x3G) connected to my PC that is sending me some ST-2110 video stream over 239.255.2.164.
I need to receive this data.
My NIC does not have any IP address assigned to it.
What IP address should I give it? Can you provide the (Linux) command to assign the IP address (along with network mask)
I am writing a C++ application that will use socket to receive this stream. I will probably use code similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243292/subscribing-to-multiple-multicast-groups-on-one-socket-linux-c

Multicast group addresses are never assigned to interfaces. They are only joined, with the OS using IGMP rather than ARP to subscribe to the corresponding packets. As others say in the linked thread, bind the local side of the socket to 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY).
As far as I know, the interface doesn't strictly need a unicast IP address assigned (it can send IGMP from 0.0.0.0), but if you want to assign one, then it should normally be chosen to match the other hosts on the same network.
